# In the co-finite topology and the co-countable topology, must $X$ be finite or countable?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Recall**

$\tau_{co-finite} = \{U \subseteq X| X\backslash U \text{ is finite}\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$

$\tau_{co-countable} = \{U \subseteq X| X\backslash U \text{ is countable}\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$

**Question**

> Must $X$ be finite (for co-finite topology) and countable (for
>   co-countable topology)?

I convinced myself that was the case until I was asked to show:

> condition on $X$ such that $\tau_{co-countable}$ is equivalent to
>   $\tau_{discrete}$

A thought: Perhaps $X$ must be uncountable?

What is should be the correct answer? Why can $X$ be any cardinality?

Comment: Those two topologies are defined on *any* set $X$, regardless of cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These topologies are always defined, for $X$ of any size. Note that we must mean "at most countable" by countable, so that it includes all finite sets (including the empty set).

There are three cases: $X$ finite, $X$ countable, and $X$ uncountable. You will see (think about it) that only for the last case these topologies and the discrete topology on $X$ are all different. In other cases some of these three will coincide.